# Netbeans 6.1 Incorrect CVS Status on a file that does not exist

Tags: netbeans, cvs, cvsnt

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours off and on now and can't figure it out.  I committed a lot of binary (jar files) to cvs and they worked fine, but one of the 6 directories, netbeans thinks has a file that it keeps trying to commit, but it doesn't actually exist in the file system.  There is also another file in the same directory that i did commit, and netbeans cvs status says that it's an unknown file, but when i delete the directory and check it out, it shows up fine, but netbeans can't get the correct cvs status for the file.

I looked in the repository and all looks fine.  There is only one file present as it should be.  Looking at the CVS directory in the checkout folder also reveals nothing suspicious.  I don't know what to do about this.  I don't know why netbeans thinks there is a file in that directory that is not actually there.  I did a search in my working directory and my netbeans project directory for any file containing a reference to this file but there is nothing.

Comment: i have verified that cvs is indeed correct by checking out the same dir that has a problem to a different path and it works fine, however i need it to be checked out into the original path where i'm having a problem because it's part of a larger dir tree.  This might have been due to me trying to rename the directory name from something with a lower case first letter to an upper case first letter with netbeans refactor.  I have tried searching through the netbeans projects dir and my cvs dir again for refs to the non-existent file netbeans keeps thinking is there but found nothing suspicious.

Comment: Ok i'm quite confident that the issue is happening because the directory used to be in lower case eg "liquid" and now it's "Liquid", but all files were committed with the "Liquid" (upper case version) however netbeans thinks there should still be files in the lower case "liquid" directory which doesn't exits and is NOT in cvs but i can't find any reference to this file anywhere in any directory related to netbeans or cvs.  I used a diff program to search again, and found references in RecentFileHistory.properties and segments but removing them did not help.

Comment: Ok i have tried renaming the "Liquid" directory to "Liquid2" then back to "liquid", then to "liquid2" then back to "Liquid" and refreshing and updating from cvs every time, to see if NetBeans 6.1 will update the file status correctly and fix this problem.  What i discovered is that now the problem manifests in more files.  Before it was only in "Liquid\file.jar", now it's in the other two files in "Liquid\other\file2.jar" and "Liquid\other\file3.zip".  So i'm sure that renaming directories and changing case is how to reproduce this problem, but i still can't fix it, Please help. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i don't know what format the file list was stored as, but deleting the nb cache seemed to do the trick.